# How to set up roles in Spring Boot when you have custom user model?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

My goal is to make a custom User model in Spring Boot and use it for authentication and authorization. It will have custom fields, but for try I will use a simple one.

So, this is my user model (User.java):

```
@Entity
public class User implements UserDetails {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    private String username;

    private String password;

    @ManyToMany
    private Set<Role> roles;

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public Set<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(Set<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }

}
```

My role model (Role.java):

```
@Entity
public class Role {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    private String name;
}
```

I have a UserController, so it is possible to register a new user (UserController.java):

```
@RestController
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @PostMapping("/users")
    public @ResponseBody
    String registerUser(@RequestParam String email,
                      @RequestParam String username,
                      @RequestParam String password) {

        User user = new User();
        user.setUsername(username);
        user.setPassword(password);
        userService.save(user);

        return "User registered";
    }
}
```

And this is my UserDetailsService implementation (UserDetailsServiceImpl.java):

```
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = this.userService.findByUsername(username);

        if(user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User doesn't exists.");
        }

        return user;
    }

}
```

And here I configured the things... (WebSecurityConfig.java):

```
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsServiceImpl() {
        return new UserDetailsServiceImpl();
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .httpBasic();
    }
}
```

**The question is where, and how I should add the roles to the user?**
In the UserDetailsServiceImpl? Or in the UserController?

I searched the whole official documentation, but it is very incomplete...
[Spring Boot Security Reference Doc.](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.3.0.RC1/reference/html5/)

Comment: Keep in mind that a request parameter for the `password` field (and/or almost any other field) is not a good idea; request parameters are intended for some other use cases. In your case, you would want to send all of that as part of the `POST` request's body.

Comment: You could either eagerly fetch the association when loading the user by username or define a separate service that is responsible to fetch the associated roles.